# How to use FILTER on a multidimensional array to retrieve unique values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I have looked at other questions similar to this but haven't seen an answer that fits with what I am trying to do.

I have a multidimensional array:

```
var arr = [
["apple","ghana",15],
["apple","brazil",16],
["orange","nigeria",10],
["banana","ghana",6]
]
```

I want to filter the array by only looking at the first column that contains the fruit name and return an array of unique values. So it will look like this:

```
var uniqueArr = [
["apple","ghana",15],
["orange","nigeria",10],
["banana","ghana",6]
]
```

I would like to provide a function that will do this. I have tried:

```
    function isUnique (rows,index,self) {
      return self.indexOf(rows) === index
    }
```

But it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what would be the deciding factor between choosing one `apple` item in the array vs selecting/returning another `apple` item in the array?

Comment: There wouldn't be a deciding factor. That's why I used the indexOf function to just find the first result in the array.

Comment: Gotcha, so the deciding factor is the first element found in the array ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `reduce` for getting the result.

```js
var arr = [["apple","ghana",15],["apple","brazil",16],["orange","nigeria",10],["banana","bangladesh",20],["banana","ghana",6]];

const res = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
 if (!a.find(v => v[0] === c[0])) {
  a.push(c);
 }
 return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array by a check if the value exists or not.

- If exist reject the element.
- If not, add the value to the set and take the element.

```js
var array = [["apple", "ghana", 15], ["apple", "brazil", 16], ["orange", "nigeria", 10], ["banana", "ghana", 6]],
    seen = new Set,
    result = array.filter(([value]) => !seen.has(value) && seen.add(value));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Never realized you could do set without calling it `()`

Comment: @TheMaster, you could create *every* instance without parenteses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const filtered = arr.filter((row, index) => arr.findIndex(row2 => row2[0] === row[0]) >= index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array to an object, using column 1 (index 0) as the key, and then convert back to an array with `Object.values()`:

```js
const arr = [["apple","ghana",15],["apple","brazil",16],["orange","nigeria",10],["banana","ghana",6]]

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((r, a) => {
    if(!r[a[0]]) r[a[0]] = a // add the item to the object, if the property doesn't exist yet
  
    return r
  }, {})
)

console.log(result)
```